# Bokeh vbar hover shows two popups instead of one

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

```
#df1 get OHLC data from  some place 
   mysource1 =  ColumnDataSource(df1)
   TOOLS = "crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
   H1=[
             ('index','@index'),
             ( 'Date', '@Date' ),        
             ( 'Open', '@Open{0.2f}'),
             ( 'Close',  '@Close{0.2f}' ),
             ( 'High','@High{0.2f}'),
             ( 'Low', '@Low{0.2f}'),        
             ( 'Volume', '@Volume{‘0.a’}' ),

         ]
   p = figure(tools=TOOLS,plot_height=900, 
                   plot_width=900, )  
   p.segment(data.index, data.High, data.index, data.Low, name = 'line', color="black" )

   p1 = p.vbar('index', w, 'Close','Open',  fill_color='Color',name="vbar1", 
                              line_color="black",source=mysource1)
   p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[p1],
                    tooltips=H1,
                    formatters={"Date": "datetime"},
                    mode='mouse')
                    )

    show(p)
```

Code above creates a chart properly but hovering on the data shows two popups instead on one.As shown in the picture

[image]

why two popups come?

Comment: Please provide a data sample that still results in the observed behavior.

Comment: The code doesn't indicate a second tooltip. Which Bokeh version do you use? In latest Bokeh it should be `formatters={"@Date": "datetime"}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i was doing in the code , some where in the code i was assigning mysource1 two times. I was assuming that it would pick up the last column source. So when i commented the second one. Two pop ups stopped. Thanks Eugene and Tony for your attention on this. So this is not an issue.